# Auto fit a Shape in a Word document

Tags: c#, vba, ms-word, vsto

How to auto fit a `Shape` in a Word document using C# or vba (Word 2013).

I have tried using the `shape.Textframe.autosize` property but it is not working. In Excel it works but in word it throws the error

> "The specified value is out of range."

```
shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = (int)Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoSize.msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText;
```

The above code does not do anything.

```
shape.TextFrame2.AutoSize = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoAutoSize.msoAutoSizeShapeToFitText;
```

The above code throws an exception of

```
"The specified value is out of range."
```

I need to auto fit a Shape in a Word file to fit the text inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the code does not work the same in Word as in Excel or PowerPoint is that Word's object model does not support `TextFrame2`'s properties. (Tested most recently in Word 365.) It only supports `TextFrame`. And `AutoSize` for `TextFrame` only supports True/False, not the `MsoAutoSize` enumeration.

Documentation for `TextFrame.AutoSize`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.textframe.autosize

Documentation for `TextFrame2.AutoSize`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.textframe2.autosize

Note that these are both for Excel (current for 365 as of this date, which means later than Office 2013). For Word there is no `TextFrame2` documentation. Word's object model accepts it as a property of the `Shape` object, but if code tries to use any of `TextFrame2`'s properties or methods it causes an error. It's not possible, for example, to use `ActiveDocument.Shapes(1).TextFrame2.TextRange.Text`.

For C#: remember that the equivalent of True is -1 (not 1). False is always 0.